# Bash script syntax - script_name $1 1 > file

Tags: bash, unix

What is the meaning of this command in bash script?

```
my_script.sh $FILE_NAME.res 1> $FILE_NAME.xml
```

Does it mean that my xml will be created only if the script runs without failing?

Comment: It just runs the command and sends stdout to `$FILE_NAME.xml`, the 1 before the redirection is superfluous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_script.sh $FILE_NAME.res 1> $FILE_NAME.xml
```

Supposing **FILE_NAME** is a variable, the script `my_script.sh` will take

**$FILE_NAME.res** as argument and redirect the standard output to **$FILE_NAME.xml**

It is suggested that you double quote the variables to avoid gobbing and word splitting

```
my_script.sh "$FILE_NAME".res 1> "$FILE_NAME".xml
```

This [[article]](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) on I/O redirections says :

> The file descriptors for stdin, stdout, and stderr are 0, 1, and 2,
>   respectively.

Regarding :

> Does it mean that my xml will be created only if the script runs
>   without failing?

In normal cases,whether your script runs as expected or not, any output(stdout) from the script will be redirected to the `.xml` file.

**Exceptions:**

1. **set -e** option will cause a script to exit when a command in the script fails. The output from the commands that followed  are not written to the file.
2. There are other redirects in the script.
3. There are multiple redirects outside the script eg. `./script >file1 >file2`. Here output will be redirected to file2 which comes last in the scene

Answer (score 1):

```
my_script.sh $FILE_NAME.res 1> $FILE_NAME.xml
   ^                  ^     ^         ^
run this script       |     |         |
             with this file |         |
               argument     |      to this file
                         redirect
                           stdout
```

`$FILE_NAME` will be expanded from whatever the environment variable `FILE_NAME` is set to.  Also note that `>` is a more common form of `1>`.